# Why does my javascript function result in a rangeError?

Tags: javascript

Fairly new to this. I read a bunch of answers with people having a similar problem. I tried all the solutions offered (using e.stopPropagation, using e.stopImmediatePropagation, using id instead of tag...) but nothing worked. I deployed a single html page through firebase. 
I wrote the script directly in the html. Here's my code:

```js
function onclick(e) {
  /*e.stopPropagation() and e.preventDefault() --YIELDD SAME RESULT*/
  e.stopImmediatePropagation()
  console.log("hello")
}
```

```html
<h3>Please update your information below</h3>
<form id="login-form" class="reset-form">
  <label>Email:</label>
  <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="@">
  <label>New Password:</label>
  <input name="password" type="password">
  <label>Confirm Password:</label>
  <input name="second-password" type="password">
  <button id="submit-button" type="button" onclick="onclick()">Update</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

**Desired behavior:** on click, button with id logs a message in the devtools console.

p.s. I'm sure there's a basic mistake I'm making but I am not able to find which one. Please help!

Comment: I see no jQuery code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` is the name of a common DOM property. When a function with this name exists in the Global scope (as yours does), it essentially becomes a property of the `window` object and can overwrite the Global one.  Call your callback function something else or move it out of the Global scope and it will work.

Also, `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` is most likely not required for your use case.

Finally, nothing can come after `</body>` except `</html>`. `<script>` elements are allowed in the `head` and `body`, but no where else.

```html
<h3>Please update your information below</h3>
<form id="login-form" class="reset-form">
  <label>Email:</label>
  <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="@">
  <label>New Password:</label>
  <input name="password" type="password">
  <label>Confirm Password:</label>
  <input name="second-password" type="password">
  <button id="submit-button" type="button" onclick="onclick1()">Update</button>
</form>

<script>
  function onclick1(e) {
    console.log("hello")
  }
</script>
```

---

Now, since you are just learning all this, let's make sure you get off on the right foot. There is soooo much bad HTML and JavaScript floating around and bad habits are still used today because most people don't know any better so they just copy/paste someone else's code that seems to work.

Don't use inline HTML event handlers (`onclick`, `onmouseover`, etc.) in the first place. Separate your JavaScript from your HTML and follow modern, standards based code. There are [many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) to not use inline HTML event handlers. Instead, use the [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method.

Next, the `<label>` element is a semantic element that works in one of two ways:

1. It has a `for` attribute that has a value that is identical to the
   form field that it is the label "for":

```html
<label for="txtFirstName">First Name:</label>
<input id="txtFirstName">
```

2. It contains the form field element that is is a label for:

```html
<label>First Name: <input id="txtFirstName"></label>
```

In either case, you are telling the client that there is a relationship between the `label` and the form field it is a label for. This allows a user to click or touch the label and activate the form field. It is also very helpful to those who rely on assistive technologies (like screen readers) to use the web.

So, putting all this together, your code reworked would look like this (I've added just a little CSS to make the page a little cleaner to look at, but none of that is required):

```css
label { display:block; width:200px; margin-bottom:.5em; }
button { margin-top: 1em; font-size:1.2em; padding:5px; }
```

```html
<h3>Please update your information below</h3>
<form id="login-form" class="reset-form">
  <label>Email: <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="@"></label>
  <label>New Password: <input name="password" type="password"></label>
  <label>Confirm Password: <input name="second-password" type="password"></label>
  <button id="submit-button" type="button">Update</button>
</form>

<script>
  // get a reference to the DOM element you want to work with
  let btn = document.getElementById("submit-button");
  
  // configure the event handler in JavaScript, not in HTML
  btn.addEventListener("click", logToConsole);
 
  // give your functions meaningful names
  function logToConsole(e) {
    console.log("hello")
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Scott, I have been using label incompletely/incorrectly the whole time. As far as my Js, i usually do separate it, but I actually didn't know it was a bad habit not to do so. This is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

`<button id="submit-button" type="button" 
onclick="onclick()">Update</button>` causes an infinite loop. You're overriding the `onclick` method which basically makes your code say "When I'm clicked, click me" ad infinitum.

Change the name of `function onclick()` to anything else, like `function hello()` and it'll work.

Here's a working codepen you can play with. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mzajGd

Comment: Please don't post code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and then your answer can lose its meaning. Just include any code right into your answer. If it's code that can be executed, make it a "code snippet".

Comment: My answer is self contained without the link. The link is just a bonus. I love external links and so do many others- gonna disagree with you on that one.

Comment: Ok, well, just trying to help. You'll find that you are in the minority about this. External links are great when they point to resources not available here. But for *your* code that you wish to show, they are frowned upon. Why would it be better for me to navigate to another site to see and try your code when I could see it and try it right here? And, what happens in the future if/when that link becomes broken? Your call.

Comment: Well, stackoverflow doesn't have support for live editing code, so it does point to a "resource not available here"...

Comment: I don't understand what your trying to say with your last comment.

Comment: A live code editor is a resource. Stackoverflow doesn't have that resource. Linking to codepen provides that resource.

Comment: Then post the link in addition to posting in within your answer. Plus, live code editing isn't really needed. If you post your code right here in your answer, I can easily copy it into my answer and modify it as needed.

Comment: Again, just trying to help you. That really is the consensus about 3rd party links here.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Changing the name worked:) I appreciate the quick response on this. Since I'm new to S O, I will also keep what you said in mind Scott.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to change which event your stopping, which seems to be the form submit. Unsure why you're getting the range issue, but this should work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="login-form" class="reset-form" >
<label>Email:</label>
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="@">
<label>New Password:</label>
<input name="password" type="password">
<label>Confirm Password:</label>
<input name="second-password" type="password">
<input type="submit">Update</button>
</form>

<script>

document.getElementById("login-form").addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('boogy');
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Hi Steve and welcome to Stack Overflow.

First place your Button, there are several ways to acomplish this:

```
<button class="ui-btn" id="cmdHello">Push Me</button>
<a href="#" class="ui-btn" id="cmdHello2">Yet another Button</a>
```

Now react to it's Click event:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).bind("pageinit", function() {
        $(document).on("click", "#cmdHello", function(evt) {
            console.log("Hello World");
        });
    });
</script>
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually address what the problem is. The OP is already hooking up an event listener. The problem is the scope of that listener and the name of the listener. Your answer shows how to set up event delegation, but misses the point of the question.